# XがCやA、Bの時に、それぞれあるアルファベットを出力したい

Tags: python

XがCやA、Bの時に、それぞれあるアルファベットが出力されるようにできますか？
例としては、X＝AのときAが出力されてX＝Bの時、Bが出力されるようにしたかったのですが、X＝AだけではAの定義をする必要があり、どのように定義すればよろしいでしょうか？

```
try:
    X = "A"
    print(A)

except :
    try:
      X = "B"
      print(B)

    except:
        try:
            X = "C"
            print(C)
        except:

            D = "D"
            print(D)
```

Comment: Pythonというかプログラミングの基本的な概念への理解が十分では無いように見える質問です。初心者向けで、ある程度まとまった内容の書籍や解説講座記事を一通り読むことをお勧めします。そうでないと、少し学習を進める毎にこうしたサイトに質問を出して、答えが来るまで待つといった効率の悪い状態が延々と続く可能性が高そうですから。例えば古いですがこんな比較記事から選んでみるとか。[【全部無料】初心者でもPythonを学習できるサービス＆サイト12選](https://blog.codecamp.jp/python-study-site) 多ければ良いという物でもないですがこれとか。[Python入門におすすめサイト19選！OS別(Mac・Windows・Linux)で厳選](https://www.dsp.co.jp/tocreator/engineer/tips-engineer/python_introductory_website/)

Comment: なぜなら、質問記事のソースに使われているのはこちら [変数の定義と値の代入](https://www.javadrive.jp/python/var/index1.html), [Pythonの例外処理！try-exceptをわかりやすく解説！](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/23044) で、作りたいことに対応しているのはこちら [if文を使った条件分岐](https://www.javadrive.jp/python/if/index1.html) だからですね。この辺のところは基礎の基礎みたいなもので、まず覚えて使えるようになっておかないと先に進むのも大変になる部分です。

Answer (score 0):

質問冒頭の「XがCやA、Bの時に」というのが何を表しているのかイマイチ不明瞭ですが、そうした条件を判定するのは`if`文です。

[8. 複合文 (compound statement) - 8.1. if 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)
[4. その他の制御フローツール - 4.1. if 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)
[if文を使った条件分岐](https://www.javadrive.jp/python/if/index1.html)

条件判定/分岐はネスト(入れ子)に出来ますが、それよりも`elif`を使って同じインデントで連続させる方が見易いですね。
**if...elif...else**

```
if 条件式1:
    実行文の並び
elif 条件式2:
    実行文の並び
elif 条件式3:
    実行文の並び
else:
    実行文の並び
```

**ifのネスト(入れ子)**

```
if 条件式1:
    実行文の並び
else:
    if 条件式2:
        実行文の並び
    else:
        if 条件式3:
            実行文の並び
        else:
            実行文の並び
```

---

なので、質問のソースに当てはめると以下のようになるでしょう。

```
A = "a" #### print()で出力する文字をあらかじめ設定しておく場合
B = "b" #### 以下同じ
C = "c"
D = "d"

if X == "A": #### 条件判定
    print(A) #### 出力したい文字を直接 print("a") とか指定しても良い
elif X == "B":
    print(B)
elif X == "C":
    print(C)
else:
    print(D)
```

---

なお、質問のソースで使われているのは代入文と例外処理なので、条件判定とは違います。
[7. 単純文 (simple statement) - 7.2. 代入文 (assignment statement)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements)
[変数の定義と値の代入](https://www.javadrive.jp/python/var/index1.html)

[8. 複合文 (compound statement) - 8.4. try 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement)
[Pythonの例外処理！try-exceptをわかりやすく解説！](https://www.sejuku.net/blog/23044)